# Why admin.addPeer() command did not add parity client for private chain with Docker?

Tags: go-ethereum, docker, openethereum

I would like to set up private chain which both geth and parity clients running on the same network.

here is a sample repository with `docker-compose` file:

https://github.com/user48736353001/devnet

After running `docker-compose up` without any errors,

docker-compose.yml

```yml
    version: '3'
    services:
      geth:
        build: geth
        ports:
          - "8545:8545"
          - "8546:8546"
        expose:
          - '30303'
        restart: always
        networks:
          app_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.16.128.20
    
      node1:
        build: parity
        ports:
          - '18545:8545'
          - '18546:8546'
        expose:
          - '30300'
        user: 'root'
        networks:
          app_net:
            ipv4_address: 172.16.128.10
    
    networks:
      app_net:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
         driver: default
         config:
           - subnet: 172.16.128.0/24
```

1. login to geth's docker container with `docker exec`
2. attach geth with `geth attach http://localhost:8545`
3. `admin.addPeer("enode://027619e7cc4c94e606ccf1f3bf2b4750f39472c001f7266c681f652c25875312ea447eefdfeb18ea193c4258a948beae66cf71de05aa64ca1fb95bbbbcdc8b1a@172.16.128.10:30303")`
4. however `admin.peers` command returns empty `[]`

Is there anything wrong with my genesis files?
I took most of the initial setting from [goerli testnet](https://github.com/goerli/testnet) with different `networkID`.

Answer (score 0):

according to your compose file, the parity peer should be `"enode://.....@172.16.128.10:30300`

Comment: sorry it was a typo when i post this. Still not be able to connect in the same network.

Comment: Port should be ‘30300’, typo also?

Comment: unfortunately yes. Just re-tried again and here are the commands:

Comment: $ docker exec -it devnet_geth_1 sh
/ # geth attach http://localhost:8545

> admin.add
admin.addPeer admin.addTrustedPeer
> admin.add
admin.addPeer admin.addTrustedPeer
> admin.addPeer("enode://84612bc106486afa56446aad5bb0b0ad4e4259dc421136174f19fd66542082ae831e3b3f6db63dd0130fef8fc6f771fa70e8111ef8d72a1dea172a2c1887da73@172.16.128.10:30300")
true
> admin.peers
[]

Comment: But default port of parity might be 30303, not 30300 as your expose

Comment: Okay, tried with exposing 30303 and but no luck...